# How to find which actual command is executed in terminal

Tags: linux, git, bash, command, alias

I have a command called `gb` (Go alternative build command) sits at ${HOME}/App/bin and that in the 'PATH'.

When I check it:

```
which gb
```

It returns correct location `${HOME}/App/bin/gb`

I also checked alias

```
alias | grep gb
```

It returns nothing.

But when I run the `gb` command from the terminal

```
$ gb
```

It always returns the result of `git branch` command.

Just want to know how could I find out what causes the hijack of the `gb` command?

Comment: `type` is the Right Thing -- but it's also worth considering `(set -x; gb)`, which will show the actual commands run by a function in practice (whereas `type gb` will show its definition).

Comment: ...in general, `which` is simply unfit for use -- being an external command, it has no way of knowing about your shell's internal state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your shell, but probably `type gb` (or `type -a gb`).

Comment: `type -a gb` might be more useful also `command -v gb` and/or `command -V gb`.

Comment: If `gb` returns a GIT sub-command then you've got a GIT alias set somewhere not a bash alias. Are you in a GIT repo when this problem happens? If so, what happens if you run: `#> git config -l  grep alias`?